# 1.9.3.2 | Module layout won't update <default>

Tags: magento-1.9, module, layout

I'm calling in a layout update from a module, from the module's `config.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>

...

    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <cmsogdata>
                    <file>cjw/cmsogdata.xml</file>
                </cmsogdata>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

...

</config>
```

It pulls the file in fine - if I put a deliberate syntax error in `cmsogdata.xml`, everything breaks as you'd expect.

What I'm trying to do is add a custom block into the HTML `<head>` on every page via `<default>` and it's not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="core/template" name="og.general" template="page/html/og-general.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>

</layout>
```

**However** if I target a specific page, such as the homepage it does work, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="core/template" name="og.general" template="page/html/og-general.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>

</layout>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Strange.It should work.

Comment: @KingshukDeb That's what I feared  :\

Answer (score 0):

Found it; I'd forgotten that I was playing crazy with this development install so in `local.xml` I was stripping everything back and overwriting it - so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml">

            <!-- [begin] html head -->
            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">

            ...
```

Which meant that `local.xml` was overwriting the module as well as Magento's own settings. Reverting it to the proper, sane, override system sorted it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <!-- default -->
    <default>

        <!-- [begin] html head -->
        <reference name="head">
```